# Best way store data when callback -Python - Django - Bokeh - Webdevelopment

Tags: django, redis, callback, bokeh, web-development-server

When doing a bokeh callback (zooming), new 500 values have to be loaded.
xRangeStart and xRangeEnd define the new needed values from the total array.
How to store this total array to get the best performance.

Redis, direct from DataBase (MongoDB), somehow else?(backend stateless)

flow:

user action on frontend --> callback call --> ajax  --> here  I need to get the new data as described --> **getting new data from total array** --> ajax returns --> source.change.emit()

the bold marked part is stored in REDIS atm (Coding with python). The callback takes some seconds when there are multiple graphs/lines within a chart (around 1sec for each arrays with a size of 3 million values). Is there a way to imporve this speed in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that the AJAX backend is Python enabled so you could try [Datashader](http://datashader.org/) to preprocess and optimise your data to be returned.

Another option is on the front-end side to replace the wheel_zoom with a "zoom slider" that has "mouseup" as callback_policy so that callback doesn't fire continuously but only on mouse release. Also having slider callback makes it possible to have a Python callback executed on Bokeh server where you could store preprocessed, optimised copy of the Redis data.

Comment: what i do at the moment:
if the ajax is in progress, the same ajax cant get called again.
if range from xtart to xend is less then 10% of the range when the last ajax was executed --> only then enable to execute the next callback.